# How flood risk is determined - Flood frequency

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If you live in a 1% AEP flood zone, you have a 50.3% chance of being flooded in a typical lifetime (70 years), and a 15.6% chance of being flooded twice in this period.

My Solution for 50.3% = 1 - exp(-70/100)

I am not quite sure about how to get 15.6%.

Will appreciate any though on that.

Comment: How did you arrive at your solution? If $X$ denotes the number of floods for someone with that age then can you find the distribution of $X$? A look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Homogeneous_Poisson_point_process) might help.

Comment: @drhab Sorry, i think you may confuse with the statement "a typical lifetime (70 years)". This statement does not refer the ages of people. it means a time frame of 70 years. Hope this is clear to you.

Comment: @drhab, could you please elaborate further? I do not follow

Comment: Have you checked the link I provided?

Comment: yes, it is tricky, though. I found it is difficult to relate with 15.6% chance of being flooded twice for 70 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well then in a $p$-AEP flood zone someone that has a lifetime of $n$ years can expect to encounter $X$ floods during his lifetime where $X$ has [Poisson-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with parameter $\lambda=np$.

So: $$P(X\geq1)=1-P(X=0)=1-e^{-np}$$ and $$P(X\geq2)=1-P(X=0-P(X=1)=1-e^{-np}-npe^{-np}$$

Substituting $p=0.01$ and $n=70$ we find the outcomes you mention.

They are answers to the question: what is the probability on at least one flood, and on at least two floods (respectively)?

If you want answers for "exactly one" and "exactlty two" then just find $P(X=1)$ and $P(X=2)$.

Comment: Many Thanks.  if i want answers for three times per 70 years. Can i go with P(X=3)?
.

Comment: Yes if it concerns "exactly three times".

Answer (score 0):

If flooding events follow a Poisson distribution with an average rate of $r = \frac 1 {100}$ per year then the probability of *no* events in a $70$ year period is

$\displaystyle P(\text {0 events}) = e^{-\frac {70}{100}} \approx 49.66 \%$

and so

$\displaystyle P(\text {at least 1 event}) = 1 - P(\text{0 events}) = 1 - e^{-\frac{70}{100}} \approx 50.34\%$

We also have

$\displaystyle P(\text {exactly 1 event}) = 0.7 \times e^{-\frac{70}{100}} \approx 34.76 \%$

so

$\displaystyle P(\text {at least 2 events}) = 1 - P(\text{0 events}) - P(\text{exactly 1 event}) = 1 - 1.7 \times e^{-\frac{70}{100}} \approx 15.58\%$

So $15.6 \%$ is a close approximation to the probability of *at least* two floods in a $70$ year period.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain me what is different between P (at least 1 event) vs p (1 event) and also where did you get 0.7 and 1.7 from?

Comment: @PonlokPeter By P(1 event) I meant P(*exactly* 1 event). I have expanded some of the calculations in my answer. You can find an explanation of the Poisson distribution at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution.

Comment: Many Thanks. Big thump up to all of you :)